# Concatenating Multiple DataFrames with Non-Standard Columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

Is there a good way to concatenate a list of DataFrames where the columns are not regular between DataFrames?

The desired outcome is to match up all columns that are a match but to keep the ones that have no match off to the side. The reason you would want to keep the unmatched columns is because while there may not be a match on a given column between the 1st and 2nd dataframes in the list there may be a match between the 1st and 3rd. Thus discarding prematurely on the first lack of match would not be ideal.

And example is:

```
print list(datalist[0].columns)
>>>[u'1', u'2', u'3']

print list(datalist[1].columns)
>>>[u'1', u'2', u'4']

print list(datalist[2].columns)
>>>[u'2', u'3', u'4']
```

Where the output would be a dataframe like (stylistically represented here):

```
1 2 3 - 
1 2 - 4
- 2 3 4
```

Comment: Can you share your expected result? Do the want to append the columns in the same position regardless of their label or do you want the table to widen as new labels are added?

Comment: @JAB sorry for the late response. Out of town. I would like to widen as new labels are added. I am surprised pandas does not have a built-in to  do this or that even someone here on SO has found a workaround. It seems like appending dataframes with slightly different column names should be not an impossible thing to do..

Comment: I don't understand the 'slightly different column names part'. If you concat vertically matching columns will overlap and new columns will widen the table.

Comment: Ah yes. You are very correct JAB. I was under the impression that using the join="outer" argument on the concat function would just append everything straight up and down vertically without regard to column names. It seems this is not the case. I must have been confused when I initially tested it. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: I think this might help others who land on this question.  I think it would be useful if if you would add a self answer and accept, rather than marking the question solved in an edit. [Self answers are encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data=pd.concat(datalist,join='outer', axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This works. I was originally under the impression that concat with the join="outer" argument applied would just append straight up and down without regard to column names. Actually, when the join="outer" argument is applied it will combine what matching columns it can but then keep all of the non-matched columns off to the side of the DF, which is exactly what is desired. Hope this helps someone else.