# Why is Pandas Concatenation (pandas.concat) so Memory Inefficient?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ram

I have about 30 GB of data (in a list of about 900 dataframes) that I am attempting to concatenate together. The machine I am working with is a moderately powerful Linux Box with about 256 GB of ram. However, when I try to concatenate my files I quickly run out of available ram. I have tried all sorts of workarounds to fix this (concatenating in smaller batches with for loops, etc.) but I still cannot get these to concatenate. Two questions spring to mind:

1. Has anyone else dealt with this and found an effective workaround? I cannot use a straight append because I need the 'column merging' (for lack of a better word) functionality of the `join='outer'` argument in `pd.concat()`.
2. Why is Pandas concatenation (which I know is just calling `numpy.concatenate`) so inefficient with its use of memory?

I should also note that I do not think the problem is an explosion of columns as concatenating 100 of the dataframes together gives about 3000 columns whereas the base dataframe has about 1000.

### Edit:

The data I am working with is financial data about 1000 columns wide and about 50,000 rows deep for each of my 900 dataframes. The types of data going across left to right are:

1. date in string format,
2. `string`
3. `np.float`
4. `int`

... and so on repeating. I am concatenating on column name with an outer join which means that any columns in `df2` that are not in `df1` will not be discarded but shunted off to the side.

---

### Example:

```
 #example code
 data=pd.concat(datalist4, join="outer", axis=0, ignore_index=True)
 #two example dataframes (about 90% of the column names should be in common
 #between the two dataframes, the unnamed columns, etc are not a significant
 #number of the columns)

print datalist4[0].head()
                800_1     800_2   800_3  800_4               900_1     900_2  0 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID  1117.1    103 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID   
1 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_ASK  1120.0    103 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_ASK   
2 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID  1106.9     11 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID   
3 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_ASK  1125.8     62 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_ASK   
4 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID  1117.1    103 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID   

    900_3  900_4              1000_1    1000_2    ...     2400_4  0  1017.2    103 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID    ...        NaN   
1  1020.1    103 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_ASK    ...        NaN   
2  1004.3     11 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID    ...        NaN   
3  1022.9     11 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_ASK    ...        NaN   
4  1006.7     10 2014-08-06 09:00:00  BEST_BID    ...        NaN   

                      _1  _2  _3  _4                   _1.1 _2.1 _3.1  _4.1  0  #N/A Invalid Security NaN NaN NaN  #N/A Invalid Security  NaN  NaN   NaN   
1                    NaN NaN NaN NaN                    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   
2                    NaN NaN NaN NaN                    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   
3                    NaN NaN NaN NaN                    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   
4                    NaN NaN NaN NaN                    NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   

      dater  
0  2014.8.6  
1  2014.8.6  
2  2014.8.6  
3  2014.8.6  
4  2014.8.6  

[5 rows x 777 columns]

print datalist4[1].head()
                150_1     150_2   150_3  150_4               200_1     200_2  0 2013-12-04 09:00:00  BEST_BID  1639.6     30 2013-12-04 09:00:00  BEST_ASK   
1 2013-12-04 09:00:00  BEST_ASK  1641.8    133 2013-12-04 09:00:08  BEST_BID   
2 2013-12-04 09:00:01  BEST_BID  1639.5     30 2013-12-04 09:00:08  BEST_ASK   
3 2013-12-04 09:00:05  BEST_BID  1639.4     30 2013-12-04 09:00:08  BEST_ASK   
4 2013-12-04 09:00:08  BEST_BID  1639.3    133 2013-12-04 09:00:08  BEST_BID   

    200_3  200_4               250_1     250_2    ...                 2500_1  0  1591.9    133 2013-12-04 09:00:00  BEST_BID    ...    2013-12-04 10:29:41   
1  1589.4     30 2013-12-04 09:00:00  BEST_ASK    ...    2013-12-04 11:59:22   
2  1591.6    103 2013-12-04 09:00:01  BEST_BID    ...    2013-12-04 11:59:23   
3  1591.6    133 2013-12-04 09:00:04  BEST_BID    ...    2013-12-04 11:59:26   
4  1589.4    133 2013-12-04 09:00:07  BEST_BID    ...    2013-12-04 11:59:29   

     2500_2 2500_3 2500_4         Unnamed: 844_1  Unnamed: 844_2  0  BEST_ASK   0.35     50  #N/A Invalid Security             NaN   
1  BEST_ASK   0.35     11                    NaN             NaN   
2  BEST_ASK   0.40     11                    NaN             NaN   
3  BEST_ASK   0.45     11                    NaN             NaN   
4  BEST_ASK   0.50     21                    NaN             NaN   

  Unnamed: 844_3 Unnamed: 844_4         Unnamed: 848_1      dater  
0            NaN            NaN  #N/A Invalid Security  2013.12.4  
1            NaN            NaN                    NaN  2013.12.4  
2            NaN            NaN                    NaN  2013.12.4  
3            NaN            NaN                    NaN  2013.12.4  
4            NaN            NaN                    NaN  2013.12.4  

[5 rows x 850 columns]
```

Comment: can you give more information in terms of: number of rows, columns per dataframe. what the types are, per field. what you're joining on.

Comment: Yes I will edit my question to answer those.

Comment: @sfortney it will help if you could add a small, complete, runnable example showing how your code works. Then we will all be on the same page. You can hand-code or randomly generate say three or four small DataFrames and show exactly how you are concatenating them in the form of code. See this recent question for a similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29629821/553404

Comment: I have edited it with code examples. I will also link to a question that has some example output.

Comment: Here is a link to another question (which I actually asked some time ago) that does exactly what I am talking about. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842681/concatenating-multiple-dataframes-with-non-standard-columns-python-pandas-solve

Comment: In general, sequentially concatenating subarrays is a slow way to produce a single large array. Concatenating `a` and `b` involves allocating a new output array the size of both `a` and `b` combined. As your output array gets longer and longer, the cost of allocating each new array gets larger and larger. It's much better to pre-allocate a single array the size of your whole output array, then fill in the rows as you go along.

Comment: Yep - see the similar case of StringBuilder classes http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: Another pandas-specific point - you will definitely want to pass `copy=False` to `pd.concat()` to avoid generating unnecessary copies

Comment: @ali_m That actually sounds like the ideal way to approach this problem. Do you have any sample code that does that? I know how I would put the data into the numpy array but I dont know how I would make the columns match up when adding in.

Comment: @sfortney Hmm, I've never before had to deal with DataFrames large enough for this to become a problem. One thing I would say is that `pd.concat` might not be that bad as long as you do it for all your subarrays in a single operation. `np.concatenate` iterates over its inputs, works out how big the output array needs to be, then preallocates it, so in principle a single call to `pd.concat` ought to be able to take care of the preallocation without you having to do it manually. What's *really* bad is looping over your subarrays and concatenating them sequentially to build your array.

Answer (score 20):

I've had performance issues concatenating a large number of DataFrames to a 'growing' DataFrame.  My workaround was appending all sub DataFrames to a list, and then concatenating the list of DataFrames once processing of the sub DataFrames has been completed.

Comment: This actually is my current workaround. It seems to work okay but I was wondering if there is an even better way. Thanks!

Comment: This cut my run time in half.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me at all. When you have a list of data frames and you want to concatenate rows (add rows to the dataframe with the same cols), do you have to do pd.concat(my_list, axis=1)?

Comment: @Konrad `axis=0` to stack them on top of each other.

Comment: Me too! Appending to a growing DataFrame becomes progressively slower. But when the types are misaligned, e.g. concatenating int64 and float64, it grinds to a halt (about 100x slower). The workaround, like @Alexander, was to concat a list of frames. But I never managed to figure out why the append was slow.

Comment: This idea doesn't work for me. I have almost 6 million rows, which I split into 1,000 rows chunks, according to this: http://deo.im/2016/09/22/Load-data-from-mongodb-to-Pandas-DataFrame/. It runs fine, but when I get to the concat point it simply stucks my computer. Any ideas?

Comment: @EliBorodach If your data is truly too big for your computer, consider using Dask (https://dask.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are trying to row-wise concat, even though you text indicates that you what column-wise. Specify `axis=1`.

Other points to consider:

`copy=False` flag will not help at all; this only matters if you are not concatting blocks of the same dtype (which you indicated you are).

`pd.concat` *does* use `np.concatenate` under the hood. If you think you can do better, then go for it.

```
def make_frames(n=100, rows=100, cols=100):
    return [ pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows,cols),columns=np.random.choice(110,100,replace=False)) for i in xrange(n) ]

In [28]: l = make_frames(rows=10000)

In [29]: l[0].head()
Out[29]: 
        60        75        101       103       87        29        10        106       71        26        30        83        2         28        99        85        88        62        58        18        42        1         105       25        34     ...          102       27        22   \
0 -0.854117 -0.007549 -0.510359 -0.993757  0.877635 -0.303199 -1.488548  1.179360  0.578095  0.807792  0.169930 -1.781403  0.204696 -0.515057 -0.954246  1.106073  0.666516 -1.146988  1.335709  0.362838 -0.675379  1.483469  0.670385 -0.483312 -0.703795    ...     1.322645 -1.942183  1.053502   
1  2.057542  0.860946 -0.037665 -0.347265  0.152562 -0.859537  1.431045  1.306419  0.623013  1.192325  0.909597  1.710507  1.319330 -0.402874  1.749581  1.223489  0.036354  0.140255  0.844330 -0.091447 -0.347245  0.259055  1.187882 -0.216858 -1.421336    ...     1.122068  0.887538  0.205854   
2 -0.077974  0.947503  0.688666  0.288104 -1.275329 -0.840847 -2.014090 -1.318507 -0.889416 -0.098005  0.055492  0.847597 -1.289428 -0.910093  0.201312 -1.699879  0.103062 -1.041608  0.379171 -1.089937  0.894626 -1.500215 -0.501182  0.042078 -0.840789    ...     0.539192  0.193256  0.196138   
3  0.291993  1.138577  1.061509  0.856553  1.118931  0.725806 -0.689776  1.337957 -1.009835 -0.976506 -0.392317  0.295876  0.092240  0.418201  0.473585  0.013809 -1.169947  0.424797  0.019051 -0.526189  0.066991 -0.268750  1.277004 -0.736560 -0.314987    ...     0.272045 -0.333272  0.573267   
4 -2.073985 -0.016950 -1.712770  0.286212 -0.159693 -0.495864  1.286450 -1.168880  1.031456 -3.080568  1.443880 -0.604405  0.406383 -0.162986  1.077255  1.160726  0.943949 -1.517681 -1.049972  1.208850 -0.859617 -0.145358 -0.638898  0.248012 -2.985845    ...    -0.699697  0.051352  0.575304   

        69        76        91        45        14        37        0         81        38        72        107       11        5         73        70        8         90        94        53        3         55        12   
0 -0.972965 -0.298674  1.283482  2.344092 -0.597735 -0.407978  0.971726 -0.935620  0.236889 -0.957096 -2.366399 -0.943760  0.293325 -0.240385 -0.392554 -0.887556  0.261402 -2.050122 -1.776865 -1.513899 -0.953916  0.630495  
1 -1.471033  0.269830 -0.744507 -0.982779  0.624527 -1.782704  1.197262 -0.297730  1.122939 -1.039226  0.171351 -0.828985  0.698245  0.563430  0.718177  0.682369  1.415918  0.049931  0.648000  1.785455 -0.190021 -1.329753  
2 -1.942792  0.560981 -0.353782 -1.637407 -1.495131 -0.593041 -1.617116 -0.910257 -0.506877  0.178378 -0.623986  0.302544  0.279309 -0.266409  0.780306  0.986510 -1.549847  0.063632 -0.480434  1.393221 -1.237682  1.577320  
3  0.468151 -1.002872 -0.147329 -0.420609  0.183696  0.527632  0.018911 -2.059989  1.642613 -0.428345  1.350693 -1.323321 -0.247263  0.331525 -2.036862 -2.593575  0.362101 -0.184095  0.419231 -0.633878  0.097499 -0.026044  
4 -0.581330 -0.848421 -0.682027 -1.260004 -0.357354 -0.304743  0.409537 -1.189925 -0.609352 -0.610345 -0.798009  0.219822 -0.681764  1.872736  1.738017  0.439148  1.012881 -0.934613 -1.007427 -0.390359  0.329949  0.486906  

[5 rows x 100 columns]
```

Concat, note using `axis=1` as this is column-wise concat.

```
In [31]: df = pd.concat(l,axis=1,ignore_index=True)

In [32]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
Columns: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
dtypes: float64(10000)
memory usage: 763.0 MB
```

Timings

```
In [33]: %timeit pd.concat(l,axis=1,ignore_index=True)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop

In [34]: %memit pd.concat(l,axis=1,ignore_index=True)
peak memory: 2390.25 MiB, increment: 651.28 MiB
```

Comment: Actually axis=0 is the correct choice. In the above comments I posted a link that demonstrates the desired output. I also did some tests with both options to make sure and axis=0 is the right choice. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: for effiecient memory utilization you can use category type for all the dtype objects.

Comment: @rajeshcis not entirely true. If there is less than 50% of them are duplicated I wouldn't convert them to categorical