# Efficient way to combine pandas data frames row-wise

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I've 14 data frames each with 14 columns and more than 250,000 rows.
The data frame have identical column headers and I would like to merge the data frames row-wise. I attempted to concatenate the data frames to a 'growing' DataFrame and it's taking several hours.

Essentially, I was doing something like below 13 times:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(13):   
    DF = pd.concat([DF, subDF])
```

The stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808739/3594865) suggests appending all sub data frames to a list and then concatenating the list of sub data frames.

That sounds like doing something like this:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame()
lst = [subDF, subDF, subDF....subDF] #up to 13 times
for subDF in lst:
    DF = pd.concat([DF, subDF])
```

Aren't they the same thing? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the suggested workflow. Here's what I tested.

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import timeit

def test1():
    "make all subDF and then concatenate them"
    numpy.random.seed(1)
    subDF = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(1))
    lst = [subDF, subDF, subDF]
    DF = pd.DataFrame()
    for subDF in lst:
        DF = pd.concat([DF, subDF], axis=0,ignore_index=True)

def test2():
    "add each subDF to the collecitng DF as you're making the subDF"
    numpy.random.seed(1)
    DF = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(3):
        subDF = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(1))
        DF = pd.concat([DF, subDF], axis=0,ignore_index=True)

print('test1() takes {0} sec'.format(timeit.timeit(test1, number=1000)))
print('test2() takes {0} sec'.format(timeit.timeit(test2, number=1000)))

>> Output

test1() takes 12.732409087137057 sec
test2() takes 15.097430311612698 sec
```

I would appreciate your suggestions on efficient ways to concatenate multiple **large** data frames row-wise. Thanks!

Comment: Did you think of maybe drop them to one csv by appending data, Then  reading that csv as DF. Shouldnt take hours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a list with all your data frames:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(13):
    df = ... # However it is that you create your dataframes   
    dfs.append(df)
```

Then concatenate them in one swoop:

```
merged = pd.concat(dfs) # add ignore_index=True if appropriate
```

This is a lot faster than your code because it creates exactly 14 dataframes (your original 13 plus `merged`), while your code creates 26 of them (your original 13 plus 13 intermediate merges).

EDIT:

Here's a variation on your testing code.

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import timeit

def test_gen_time():
    """Create three large dataframes, but don't concatenate them"""
    for i in range(3):
        df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(10**6))

def test_sequential_concat():
    """Create three large dataframes, concatenate them one by one"""
    DF = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(3):
        df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(10**6))
        DF = pd.concat([DF, df], ignore_index=True)

def test_batch_concat():
    """Create three large dataframes, concatenate them at the end"""
    dfs = []
    for i in range(3):
        df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(10**6))
        dfs.append(df)
    DF = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

print('test_gen_time() takes {0} sec'
          .format(timeit.timeit(test_gen_time, number=200)))
print('test_sequential_concat() takes {0} sec'
          .format(timeit.timeit(test_sequential_concat, number=200)))
print('test_batch_concat() takes {0} sec'
          .format(timeit.timeit(test_batch_concat, number=200)))
```

Output:

```
test_gen_time() takes 10.095820872998956 sec
test_sequential_concat() takes 17.144756617000894 sec
test_batch_concat() takes 12.99131180600125 sec
```

The lion's share corresponds to generating the dataframes. Batch concatenation takes around 2.9 seconds; sequential concatenation takes more than 7 seconds.

Comment: @sedeh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.